how to pass List<String> to putExtra
I'm making a music player in Kotlin, I translated java code from the Internet to Kotlin, but I can't pass List to putExtra, could you tell me how and where to beat it so that everything is calmly transmitted to me. The List contains the path to the song.
MainActivity:
package com.example.zevamusic

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.widget.AdapterView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import java.io.File

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var listView: ListView
    private lateinit var items: List<String>

    private val PERMISSION_STORAGE = 101

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listSongs)
        getSongs()
        ZaprosPermission()
    }
    fun ZaprosPermission(){
        if (PermissionUtils.hasPermissions(this@MainActivity)) return
        PermissionUtils.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity, PERMISSION_STORAGE)

    }

    private fun findSong(file: File): List<File> {
        val arrayList = mutableListOf<File>()
        val files = file.listFiles() ?: return arrayList
        for (singleFile in files) {
            if (singleFile.isDirectory && !singleFile.isHidden) {
                arrayList.addAll(findSong(singleFile))
            } else {
                if (singleFile.name.endsWith(".mp3")) {
                    arrayList.add(singleFile)
                }
            }
        }
        return arrayList
    }

    private fun getSongs() {
        val songs = findSong(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())
        items = songs.map { it.name.replace(".mp3", "") }
        val songsAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items)
        listView.adapter = songsAdapter

        listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val song = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
            val intent = Intent(this, PlayerActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("songs",songs)
                putExtra("song", song)
                putExtra("position", position)
            }
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }

}


I tried to fix it but my attempts are unsuccessful...

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Unfortunately Lists are not able to be directly passed as an extra between activities. Best solution for passing a list would be do something where you pass a Parcelable object. Something like this SO answer would probably be your best bet. The accepted answer on that same question would also be a good implementation.
EDIT:
Here's some help for implementation.
In your build.gradle (:app) file
Make sure you have the new id 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin, as the androidExtensions is now deprecated. Should look something like this:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}

Don't forget to re-sync gradle after making the plugin change.
In your MainActivity class
I'd make the following changes -
At the top of the file, for ease of access, turn the extra's into const val string keys. (I'd also maybe move that PERMISSION_STORAGE up here too).
const val EXTRA_SONGS_LIST = "songs"
const val EXTRA_SONG_PATH = "song"
const val EXTRA_SONG_POSITION = "position"

Your getSongs() function should be as follows, where you're passing a Parcelable object now for the songs.
private fun getSongs() {
    val songs = findSong(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())
    items = songs.map { it.name.replace(".mp3", "") }
    val songsAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items)
    listView.adapter = songsAdapter

    listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
        val song = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
        val parcelableSongs = songs.map { ParcelableSong(it) } as ArrayList
        val intent = Intent(this, PlayerActivity::class.java).apply {
            putParcelableArrayListExtra("songs", parcelableSongs)
            putExtra("song", song)
            putExtra("position", position)
        }
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}

The above code block where we putParcelableArrayListExtra is now utilizing a new data class created. My recommendation would be putting it at the bottom of the file (after the final closing curly brace } of the class that is calling putParcelableArrayListExtra).
@Parcelize data class ParcelableSong(
    val song: File
) : Parcelable

In your PlayerActivity class
(Basing "PlayerActivity class" on the Intent PlayerActivity::class.java line)
In your function that is fetching the data, you'll want something like this:
private fun displaySongStuff() {
    val songFiles: ArrayList<ParcelableSong>? = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_SONGS_LIST, ParcelableSong::class.java)
    } else {
        intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_SONGS_LIST)
    }
    if (songFiles == null) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to get song files")
        return
    }
    val song = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_SONG_PATH)
    val position = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_SONG_POSITION, -1)
    if (position == -1) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to get song position")
        return
    }
}

Keep in mind, you'll probably need to change some things here and there to have it work with your specific code.
Hope this helps!

could you help me implement this with my Activiry, I just can't quite figure out how to use your hints

@ADESGAMES Just edited my answer with hopefully all the information you'll need to get going :)
